# Select only one area on SVG map using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, raphael

I am using Mapael, a Raphael extension in order to deliver an interactive map, so far I have coded it so you can select multiple areas and make a div element visible according to the area clicked, and now I would like to be able to restrict the user to only selecting one area at a time.

http://plnkr.co/edit/2UAl4Yax99dJAPIDWuTy?p=preview

here is the part of the code that covers the click function.

```
eventHandlers: {
    click: function(e, id, mapElem) {
        var newData = {
            'areas': {}
        };
        if (mapElem.originalAttrs.fill == "#f4f4e8" && "id[^='department']") {
            newData.areas[id] = {
                attrs: {
                    fill: "#0088db"
                }
            };
            $('#' + id).css("visibility", "visible")
        }
        else if (mapElem.originalAttrs.fill == "#0088db" && "id[^='department']") {
            newData.areas[id] = {
                attrs: {
                    fill: "#f4f4e8"
                }
            };
            $("#" + id).css("visibility", "hidden")
        }
        $(".mapcontainer").trigger('update', [newData]);
    }
},
```

Again, the map shown here allows you to click multiple areas, however I would like to make it so you can just select one area at a time.

I've tried for quite a while coming up with a solution myself, however I think I've had coders block somewhat and could do with a little advice to point me in the right direction. I've been experimenting with .bind, .target and also with the mapael afterUpdate capabilites (shown below if it can help).

```
var options = {
  mapOptions: {},             // was updatedOptions
  replaceOptions: false       // replace opt.resetPlots/resetAreas: whether mapsOptions should entirely replace current map options, or just extend it,
  newPlots: {},               // was newPlots
  newLinks: {},               // was opt.newLinks
  deletePlotKeys: [],         // was deletedPlots
  deleteLinkKeys: [],         // was opt.deletedLinks
  setLegendElemsState: true,  // is new
  animDuration: 0,            // was opt.animDuration
  afterUpdate: function(){}   // was opt.afterUpdate
};
$(".container").trigger('update', [options]);
```

I'm not sure if the solution could be something like looping through the SVG paths when first clicked to ensure that no element has been clicked/has the blue fill, and then going from there? Although this sounds a bit overly complicated to me and I'm not sure how it would be implemented in practice.

Comment: Remember what was last clicked on and reset its colour on the next click.

Comment: Would I be doing that inside an else if statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to this problem, here is a plnkr of it;

```
eventHandlers: {
                    click: function (e, id, mapElem, textElem) {
                        var newData = {
                            'areas': {}
                        };

                        if (previousSelectedElementId !== null) {
                            newData.areas[previousSelectedElementId] = {
                                attrs: {
                                    fill: "#5ba4ff"
                                }
                            };
                        }

                        if (mapElem.originalAttrs.fill == "#5ba4ff") {
                            newData.areas[id] = {
                                attrs: {
                                    fill: "#0088db"
                                }
                            };
                            previousSelectedElementId = id;
                        } else {
                            newData.areas[id] = {
                                attrs: {
                                    fill: "#5ba4ff"
                                }
                            };
                            previousSelectedElementId = null;
                        }
                        $(".mapcontainer").trigger('update', [newData]);
                    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/neveldo/wfftgu20/